# Symfony2 persist a ManyToOne with attributes

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

This error appears when I try to persist my entity :

> Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer
>   given in
>   C:\wamp\www\projet\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php
>   line 1601

This is my entity Site :

```
/**
 * Etablissement
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Intranet\RhBundle\Entity\SiteRepository")
 */
class Site {
 /**
  * @var integer
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
  * @ORM\Id
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
  */
 private $id; /**
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Intranet\RhBundle\Entity\SiteEtablissement",
 mappedBy="site", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
  * */
 private $siteEtablissements;
 }
```

This is my entity Etablissement :

```
/**
* Etablissement
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Intranet\RhBundle\Entity\EtablissementRepository")
*/
class Etablissement {

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
}
```

And the entity for the relation :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Intranet\RhBundle\Entity\SiteEtablissementRepository")
 */
class SiteEtablissement {

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Intranet\RhBundle\Entity\Site", inversedBy="siteEtablissements")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="site_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $site;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Intranet\RhBundle\Entity\Etablissement")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="etablissement_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $etablissement;
}
```

So I don't understand why I have this error, my mapping seems to be ok. I don't have any entity error and I have no error before to persist $site in my controller.

This is my controller :

```
public function gererEtablissementAction(Request $request, Site $site) {
    $form = $this->createForm(new GererSiteEtabType(), $site);
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            foreach ($site->getSiteEtablissements() as $sitEtab)
                if (is_null($sitEtab->getAutor()))
                    $sitEtab->setAutor($this->getUser());
            $em->persist($site);
            $em->flush();
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', "Les établissement du site " . $site->getNom() . " ont été modifiés avec succès !");
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('intranet_rh_homepage_employes'));
        } else
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('danger', "Erreur de formulaire !");
    }
    return $this->render('IntranetRhBundle:Site:gererEtablissement.html.twig', array('site' => $site, 'form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

When I print $site->getSiteEtablissements, there are Site and Etablissement on each side of each object...

This is the build form :

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('siteEtablissements', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new SiteEtablissementType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'required' => false
            ))
    ;
}
```

And the subform :

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('etablissement', 'entity', array(
                'label' => 'Etablissement :',
                'class' => 'IntranetRhBundle:Etablissement',
                'property' => 'nom',
                'query_builder' => function(EtablissementRepository $er) {
            // récupère les établissements triés par ordre alpabétique  croissant de nom
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->orderBy('e.nom', 'ASC');
        },
                'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')
            ))
    ;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you persist `$sitEtab` instead of `$site`? Also is the result of `$this->getUser()` an object?

Comment: I have the same error if I try to persist $sitEtab in the loop.
I already have this kind of relation and form in my project but without this error although the code is similar...

Comment: My guess is that somewhere in a relation you are giving an object id instead of the object itself, but from the code you posted i can't spot none

Comment: In the log file there is no insert query.
There is this request written before the request CRITICAL line :

doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.inscription_date AS inscription_date2, t0.site_id AS site_id3, t0.etablissement_id AS etablissement_id4, t0.autor AS autor5 FROM SiteEtablissement t0 WHERE t0.site_id = ? [1] []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the error : a bad initialsiation of Autor.
Autor was initialise at "0" and in the loop I test if is_null. So 0 is not null and when it persists, there is an error ebcause there is no user with id 0...